# Permanently change Safari Custom User Agent editing the plist file

Tags: macos, safari, monterey

I need help with changing Safari's user agent permanently by editing the plist file.

Usually one would go to **Preferences** > **Advanced** > **Show Developer mode in menu bar**. Then **Develop** > **User Agent** > **Chrome - Windows** for example. However, when you open a new tab or window, this goes back to Default (Safari). This is expected behaviour.
In the past, it was possible to edit a line that determined the user agent in `/Users/(user)/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist`.

There was a line called: `CustomUserAgent`. It's not there anymore. How can I create it (with defaults probably) with the user agent of Chrome (Mac)? Alternatively, is there another way to change it, or has the procedure changed? I called Apple Support to no avail.

This is an old trick as the CustomUserAgent string is not there anymore. Forum article for reference: ["Permanently change Safari's User Agent string"](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090630112653430)

I tried also [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148323/make-custom-user-agent-change-permanent), but when I use the default write command it seems not to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: BE VERY CAREFUL DISABLING System Integrity Protection.

the plist file is now located in /System/Library/Preferences/. You can edit this by **logging in as root** (see [Enable Root User](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012#:%7E:text=1%20Choose%20Apple%20menu%20%3E%20Log%20Out%20to,users%2C%20click%20Other%2C%20then%20log%20in.%20See%20More)), disabling System Integrity Protection from recovery with csrutil -disable and csrutil authenticated-root disable (go find a tutorial) unmounting the system snapshot, and mounting a folder to that disk (for example if your disk was called /dev/disk1s3, you would run

```
sudo mkdir mnt
sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/disk1s3 mnt/
```

go into /private/var/root/mnt (should show disk icon and appear as Macintosh HD or name of your boot volume)

You can change the defaults to your user agent with this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent "\"useragentstring\""
```

On Intel Mac run:

```
sudo bless --folder mnt/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot && sudo dsenableroot -d && sudo reboot
```

or on Apple Silicon:

```
 sudo bless --mount "mnt/System/Library/CoreServices/" --setBoot --create-snapshot && sudo dsenableroot -d && sudo reboot
```

then you're done!

Comment: Why are you blessing a partition in which you only edit an unspecified Preference plist?